# Print clang include path and store in file

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, stdout, stderr, clang

I'm writing a program that needs to pull in the clang include paths. Thanks to [Dump include paths from g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946294/dump-include-paths-from-g) I'm half-way there. The command I'm using is:

```
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
```

The problem here is that I can't shell redirect the output of the above command to stdout or stderr.

```
# These fail to retrieve the include paths
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null > stdout.txt
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null 2> stderr.txt
```

So where is the output being redirected to and what command do I need to execute to properly store off the information that is printed to console?

Comment: Some of the result of that command is going to standard output, and some is going to standard error. You can also redirect both with `clang++ ... >out 2>err`.  When I do this, nothing is printed on the terminal. I'm not entirely sure I understand your issue.

Comment: the output of my program creates a ton of newlines, which is why I thought stderr was giving me incomplete input but I am mistaken